# Can someone explain this formula for determining collinear points

Tags: geometry

Trying to understand some code I am looking at. If you have three latlong points, p1 p2 and p3.

You want to determine if they are on a line.

You work out:

X.Lat = p1.Lat - p2.Lat

X.Long = p1.Long - p2.Long

Y.Lat = p3.Lat - p2.Lat

Y.Long = p3.Long - p2.Long

Then you do some crazyness

Cosang = ( X.Lat * Y.Lat + x.Long * y.Long ) / ( Sqrt( x.Lat^2 + x.Long^2 ) * Sqrt ( Y.Lat^2 + y.Long^2 ) )

If Abs(Cosang) > 0.997 they are collinear?

How does that work?

Comment: Oh thanks, I will try to figure that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transcript your formulas into readable form (longitude et latitude are resp. $x$ and $y$ coordinates).

The first groupe makes $(X_2,Y_2)$ a new origin :

$X=X_1-X_2 \ $ and $ \ Y=Y_1-Y_2$,

$X'=X_3-X_2 \ $ and $ \ Y'=Y_3-Y_2.$

Then the big formula reads

$$XX'+YY'=\cos \alpha \sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \sqrt{X'^2+Y'^2}$$

which links the two ways of expressing a dot product.

The test, more or less, means $\cos(\alpha)=+1$ or $-1$:

In the case $+1$, the points are aligned in the order $A_2,A_1,A_3$ or $A_2,A_3,A_1.$

In the case $-1$, the points are aligned in the order $A_1,A_2,A_3$.

Taking $abs(cos(\alpha))>0.997$ groups the two cases, including cases where the alignment is only approximate.

Comment: Thank you so much. The bit about two ways of expressing a dot product is what made it click for me. 

I have no idea how  you took that jumbled mess of a question and gave me the exact answer I needed - but I am grateful.